# Query documents (text search) in Restheart

Tags: mongodb, restheart

I created a collection and indexed the field as "text" in mondo shell.
Then I query documents with the following parameters:

```
localhost:8080/db/tags?filter={"$text":{"$search":"some text"}}
```

and get error:

```
http status code 500
http status description "Internal Server Error"
message "Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'Too many text expressions' on server 127.0.0.1:27017"
```

But in mongo shell everything is OK. I got the rigth response on this query:

```
db.tags.find({"$text":{"$search":"some text"}})
```

What's wrong? I did everything by these tutorials:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-query-examples

https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/RH/pages/10747996/Query+Documents#QueryDocuments-filteringFiltering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to re-create the index with RESTHeart instead of Mongo shell.

First, delete the index with the shell, then create it again by following the examples at: https://restheart.org/learn/indexes/

For example, you can create a named index for the collection `tags` with the following:

```
PUT /db/tags/_indexes/<index_id> {"keys": {"title": "text" }}

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
```

Then please let us know if it works.

**Updated**:

Here what I did to successfully test a full text search on RESTHeart (BTW I'm using the httpie client, but curl would work similarly):

1. cd into RESTHeart folder
2. start dockerized RESTHeart with `docker-compose up`

Then issue the following commands:

Creare a db

`http -a admin:changeit PUT http://localhost:8080/mydb`

Create a collection

`http -a admin:changeit PUT http://localhost:8080/mydb/sample`

POST sample documents

`http -a admin:changeit POST http://localhost:8080/mydb/sample < sample.json`

Create a collection index named "about" which uses the "about" element in JSON documents for text indexing and searching

`http -j -a admin:changeit PUT http://localhost:8080/mydb/sample/_indexes/about keys:='{"about":"text"}}'`

Check the index

`http -a admin:changeit GET http://localhost:8080/mydb/sample/_indexes`

Perform successful full text search

`http -a admin:changeit GET http://localhost:8080/mydb/sample?filter='{"$text":{"$search":"\"Consequat fugiat commodo irure\""}}'`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location, ETag, Auth-Token, Auth-Token-Valid-Until, Auth-Token-Location, X-Powered-By
Auth-Token: 240ym6d4sbxujjl8qa0ezslyfcpx7tmrjo4lfqmcxx9uirjjcs
Auth-Token-Location: /_authtokens/admin
Auth-Token-Valid-Until: 2018-09-19T07:46:37.717Z
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 793
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 07:31:37 GMT
ETag: 5ba11d9aa7b11b0006d54c5f
X-Powered-By: restheart.org

{
    "_embedded": [
        {
            "_etag": {
                "$oid": "5ba11db6a7b11b0006d54c61"
            }, 
            "_id": "5ba11d3ffb91c9eb48eee9f2", 
            "about": "Nulla pariatur eu dolor ad fugiat cillum. Ex consectetur id velit officia veniam pariatur nisi ea et nisi aliquip reprehenderit adipisicing incididunt. Exercitation esse mollit in pariatur eiusmod veniam quis est consequat ad. Fugiat eu excepteur fugiat incididunt et. Consequat fugiat commodo irure id magna in magna minim non anim amet. Officia ipsum veniam excepteur consequat labore.", 
            "address": "923 Sheffield Avenue, Wescosville, California, 2455", 
            "age": 20, 
            "balance": "$1,335.75", 
            "company": "FLEXIGEN", 
            "email": "terra.gross@flexigen.name", 
            "eyeColor": "blue", 
            "favoriteFruit": "strawberry", 
            "friends": [
                {
                    "id": 0, 
                    "name": "May Rowland"
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 1, 
                    "name": "Schmidt Herman"
                }, 
                {
                    "id": 2, 
                    "name": "Saundra Shepard"
                }
            ], 
            "greeting": "Hello, Terra! You have 6 unread messages.", 
            "guid": "c529609b-8535-4aea-a386-d3861e3fe831", 
            "index": 3, 
            "isActive": false, 
            "latitude": "-43.467295", 
            "longitude": "114.929505", 
            "name": {
                "first": "Terra", 
                "last": "Gross"
            }, 
            "phone": "+1 (956) 474-2649", 
            "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32", 
            "range": [
                0, 
                1, 
                2, 
                3, 
                4, 
                5, 
                6, 
                7, 
                8, 
                9
            ], 
            "registered": "Saturday, February 17, 2018 1:13 PM", 
            "tags": [
                "excepteur", 
                "velit", 
                "sint", 
                "sit", 
                "eu"
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "_etag": {
        "$oid": "5ba11d9aa7b11b0006d54c5f"
    }, 
    "_id": "sample", 
    "_returned": 1
}
```

You'll find the [sample.json.zip](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/files/2395815/sample.json.zip) file in attachment.

I'd suggest to compare the above steps with what you are doing and see if there are remarkable differences.